# Brightness control (Fn+ ...) not working on Ubuntu 14.04 Asus Q502LA

Tags: 14.04, brightness, asus

I installed the Ubuntu 14.04 on Asus Q502LA laptop.  Most of the things work fine, but brightness control does not work.
First, everytime on reboot, the brightness resets to 100% brightness.
Second, the keys (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>) do not work either.

I tried pretty much all of the suggestions that I could find here.  None of them worked.
Did anyone have any success with getting the Fn+ keys working again to control the brightness in 14.04?

Thanks,

Comment: Run `acpi_listen` in a terminal and press both `Fn+F5` and `Fn+F6`. What's the output?

Comment: Thanks for the advise, #kos.  I ran the listener .  When pressing Fn+F5 and Fn+F6, there is no action from acpi_listen (ie the combo does not trigger an event)

Comment: Do the other Fn combos work correctly?

Comment: yes, the other Fn keys work fine with an exception for the airplane mode (Fn+F2).  The airplane mode light is always on even though I have wifi but that is another issue I believe.

Comment: Ok, are both `asus_wmi` and `asus_nb_wmi` modules loaded? You can check it with `lsmod`

Comment: I will check that first thing tomorrow morning and give an update.  Thanks!

Comment: I checked my machine and indeed both modules asus_wmi and asus_nb_wmi are loaded.  What do I do next?

Comment: That's what i have on the topic, sorry :) i upvoted your question as i'm interested as well, since my wifi hotkey has the same issue

Comment: For Asus laptops `acpi_osi=` boot parameter helps in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question...
... so at the end after all the sufferings and bumps I ended up switching to openSuse.  Never looked at Ubuntu Unity again, since openSuse does not have any of the problems I have been facing with Unity.

It is my personal opinion, but I think Unity is still a raw meat, while openSuse is a sizzling pepper steak.